# Detect caps lock on/off using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, capslock

I can be trying the registration Form and the detection caps lock is on or off showing a warning under confirm password (WARNING! caps lock is on/WARNING! caps lock is off)

Wwhen I press capslock (caps lock is on) then shows a warning completely but when I press capslock (caps lock is off) then not show a stop warning

```js
window.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
  var isCaps = event.getModifierState('CapsLock');
  if (isCaps) {
    //true
    document.getElementById('alert').innerText = " WARNING! caps lock is on";
  } else {
    //false
    document.getElementById('alert').innerText = "";
  }
})
```

```html
My HTML code looks like this:

<form action="#" method="post" keyup="validate()">
  <h1>login Form</h1>
  <div>
    <label for="username">username</label>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username">

  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="password">password</label>
    <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="password">

  </div>
  <div>
    <label>confirm password</label>
    <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" onkeyup="check(this)">
    <br>
    <error id="alert"> </error>

  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button">submit</button>

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: your code works as expected - you display a warning when caps lock is on ... you display NOTHING when it is off

Comment: Converted to a snippet for you.   As above, works fine in the snippet.  If it's not working for you (clearing the warning when caps off) then please update the snippet and provide enough code to *demonstrate* the issue.

Comment: If the issue is really that it doesn't show "caps lock is off" then a) you don't want two nearly-identical warnings (different by on/off) and need something else such as a tick icon / warning triangle icon.   And b) please read through the code you've provided.

Comment: I placed your updated code in another snippet - it's still working fine. If it's not working for you then there's another underlying problem (aside from the missing `check()` function definition)

Answer (score -1):

hi change the event to keyDown

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  let isCaps = event.getModifierState("CapsLock");
  console.log(isCaps);
  if (!isCaps) {
    document.getElementById("alert").innerText = "";
  } else {
    //true
    document.getElementById("alert").innerText = " WARNING! caps lock is on";
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="app.js" defer></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="alert"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's working the same in my code but when I off caps lock then not show warnings

Comment: *then not show warning* - because your warning for *off* is `""`

Comment: @freedomn-m  is right .
I just tested it in the console on a boolean .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).